# How to convert json array to objects array Alamofire?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I have such array in from api:

```
[{
    data = "";
    datetime = "23.07.2020 12:09";
    id = 340593;
    status = "My current task is";
},...]
```

I have created such struct:

```
struct RemarksModel {
    let id:Int
    let status,datetime:String
    let data:String?
}
```

And here I make request:

```
AF.request(URLRequest(url:Pathes.init(endpoint: "notepad/\(noteModel?.id ?? 0)/documentation").resourseUrl),
                   interceptor: CallInterceptor.init(method:HTTPMethod.get)).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
                    print(response.description)
                    switch response.result{
                    case .success(let array):
                        let remarksData = array as? [RemarksModel]
                        
                        let json = response.data as? [RemarksModel]
                        
                        
                        print(json?.count)
                        
                        
//                        if remarksData?.count ?? 1 > 0{
//                            self.remarksArray += remarksData!
//                            self.tableView.reloadData()
//                        }
                        
                        
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        
                    }
                    
                   })
```

the problem is that I can't convert this array to array of my model objects. when I try to add all received data to array my app crashes because my array is nil, despite of json in logs. Maybe I have to use another way of converting received json array to objects array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `Codable` protocol to `RemarksModel` and use `.responseData` instead of `.responseJSON`

```
.responseData { response in
    switch response.result {
    case let .success(data):
        do {
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([RemarksModel].self, from: data)
            // success
        } catch {
            print("decoding error:\n\(error)")
            // error
        }
    case let .failure(error):
        // error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use directly `.responseDecodable` function instead of `.responseData` or `.responseJSON` after confirming `RemarksModel` to `Codable` (or just `Decodable`) protocol

```
.responseDecodable(of: [RemarksModel].self, queue: .main, decoder: JSONDecoder()) { (response) in
    switch response.result {
    case let .success(data):
        // success
        print(data)
    case let .failure(error):
        // error
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```